# Python lxml поиск элементов - потомков первого уровня

Tags: python, html, парсер, lxml, cssselect

Имеется html-код:

```
<div class="block_content_inner">
    <div class="details_block">
        <b>Название:</b> Fractured Lands<br>

        <b>Жанр:</b> 
        <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/genre/Action/?snr=1_5_9__408">Экшены</a>, <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/genre/Early%20Access/?snr=1_5_9__408">Ранний доступ</a><br>

        <div class="dev_row">
            <b>Разработчик:</b>

            <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/search/?developer=Unbroken%20Studios&amp;snr=1_5_9__408">Unbroken Studios</a>
        </div>

        <div class="dev_row">
            <b>Издатель:</b>

            <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/search/?publisher=Unbroken%20Studios&amp;snr=1_5_9__408">Unbroken Studios</a>           
        </div>


                <b>Дата выхода:</b> 31 июл. 2018<br>


    <div class="details_block">.....</div>
</div>
```

Необходимо вытащить информацию о жанрах. Ссылки представляют собой потомки первого уровня

Код:

```
genres = []

block_content_inner = html.cssselect('div.block_content_inner>div.details_block')[0]
genres_list = block_content_inner.cssselect('a')
for genre_list in genres_list:
    genres.append(genre_list.text)        

print('Жанры:',genres)
```

Как можно указать в css-селекторах искать только среди потомков первого уровня?

Текущий вывод: `Жанры: ['Экшены', 'Ранний доступ', 'Unbroken Studios', 'Unbroken Studios']`
Ожидаемый вывод: `Жанры: ['Экшены', 'Ранний доступ']`

Comment: У меня текущий вывод: `IndexError: list index out of range`, потому что в примере html нет div.block_content_inner ;)

Comment: Исправил разметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто, нужно указывать что тег `a` является вложенным в `.details_block`, в css селекторе для этого используется символ `>`:

```
css_selector = 'div.block_content_inner > div.details_block:first-child > a'
genres = [genre_list.text for genre_list in html.cssselect(css_selector)]
print('Жанры:', genres)
# Жанры: ['Экшены', 'Ранний доступ']
```

Comment: Ваш код ищет ссылки среди всей страницы:

Comment: Жанры: ['Экшены', 'Ранний доступ', '\r\n\t\t\tПосетить сайт ', '\r\n\t\t\tПросмотреть историю обновлений\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\tПрочитать соответствующие новости\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\tПросмотреть обсуждения\t\t', '\r\n\t\tНайти группы сообщества\t']

Comment: @danilshik, в примере в вопросе он ищет правильно :) Подправил, проверьте

Comment: Ваш код работал бы, если бы на странице был бы 1 div class='details_block'. Но в разметке показано 2. Просто я во 2 блоке не вставил код, а поставил многоточие

Comment: @danilshik, согласен. Проверили текущий селектор после обновления ответа?

Comment: Да, ответ такой же. Необходимо исключить 2 div.details_block. Может есть css-селектор который ищет только первого потомка?

Comment: `'div.block_content_inner > div.details_block:first-child > a'`?

Comment: @danilshik, я кст тоже стим парсил, только мне нужно было искать цены играм: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/691428a90d93700cc96e1865940c3340f026732f/get_price_game/from_steam.py :)

Comment: цены к играм я в отдельном парсере сделал, а этот парсер чисто чтобы инфомацию об играх заполнить

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Отредактируйте ваш ответ

Comment: Точнее, этот парсер (он активно используется) https://github.com/gil9red/price_of_games/blob/fd0e047f5d418ee57e5cec0ad425231b8eeb1ab6/common.py#L700 А можете скинуть ссылку на свой парсер цен? :)

Comment: Почему вы используете bs4? Он же проигрывает lxml. HTML вроде не битый, чтобы его использовать. Хотяы бы в bs4 используйте lxml, а не html.parser

Comment: А по поводу моего парсера, я еще не реализовал добавление в бд, так как самой бд еще нет

Comment: Но если интересно, могу выложить на github

Comment: Потому что bs4 удобнее lxml, да и не нужно устанавливать lxml. Проигрывает в плане скорости и использования памяти, а мне это не важно -- скрипт работает редко и данных мало. `html.parser` использую как раз по причине того, что не хочу зависимости от lxml. Да, это интересно посмотреть код на github :)

Comment: https://github.com/danilshik/Parsers/blob/develop/steam_price.py

Comment: @danilshik, быстро вы :)